# c# return values from main thread periodically

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unity-game-engine

In my `BackgroundWorker`, I need to construct and proccess various data periodically with a non-thread save API. I know that it is possible to invoke on the main thread with a queue of Actions, but I don't know how to return a value from this queue.

So how could this be done? Or is there a even better approach than with a `BackgroundWorker`?

I only found soulutions with `this.Invoke` so far, but I can't use them since the API (Unity 5 Engine) doesn't provide similar functions.

My enviroment only supports .NET 2.0 by the way.

**EDIT: I might need to give some exampels**

Assuming the constructur of `Foo` can only be called from the mainthread, I need to do this

```
TheInvokeMethode(() => { FooArray[i] = new Foo();});
SomeMethode(FooArray[i]);
```

or assumming `AddComponent()` of `Bar` can only be called from the MainThread

```
Bar SomeBar;
TheInvokeMethode(() => { SomeBar.AddComponent()});
```

However `TheInvokeMethode` is just something to express that the containing code should be executed on the MainThread.

Comment: If you are using Unity3D you should add it to the tags. BackgroundWorker as I remember is a part of Windows.Forms which is not available in Unity3D.

Comment: @Vlad nope, BackgroundWorker is on `ComponentModel`, don't know if Unity has it, but it's not linked to `Windows.Forms` other than having a handy control to drop in it. It should work wherever there's a `SynchronizationContext` (same as `Task.Run`)

Comment: @Jcl there is no SynchronizationContext for Unity main thread. you can write it yourself.

Comment: As it looks by [this link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1040862/using-backgroundworker-with-unity-completed-not-ru.html), it seems `BackgroundWorker` is indeed available in `Unity`, however judging by the answer in that forum, I'm not sure Unity uses a `SynchronizationContext` at all

Comment: @Vlad yeah, it looks like so... I've never used Unity so I was just guessing. Just pointing out that `BackgroundWorker` is not tied to Windows.Forms at all

Comment: In my answer I provided a Unity implementation of Control.Invoke. Is that what you need? Please take a look.

Comment: If code is not thread-safe, that does not imply it has to be executed on the main thread (which is what your question seems to take as a given). So delegating to the main thread is pointless, you can just run it from your worker thread, provided you make sure only one thread executes the code at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

In Unity you can make your own Invoke which will work the same way as Control.Invoke:

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading;

    public class UnityInvoker : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public UnityInvoker Instance { get; private set; }

        void Awake()
        {
            Instance = this;
            _updateThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        }

        Action _stored;
        object _lock = new object();
        volatile Thread _updateThread;

        public void Invoke(Action action)
        {
            if (_updateThread == Thread.CurrentThread)
            {
                lock (_lock) _stored += action;
                Update();
                return;
            }
            using (var waiter = new ManualResetEvent(false))
            {
                action += () => waiter.Set();
                lock (_lock)
                    _stored += action;
                waiter.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        void Update()
        {
            _updateThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
            Action toDo;
            lock (_lock)
            {
                toDo = _stored;
                _stored = null;
            }
            if (toDo != null)
                toDo();
        }
    }
```

Place it on any game object.

Usage:

```
UnityInvoker.Instance.Invoke(()=>Application.Quit());
```

It can be optimized (if required) with Interlocked.

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundWorker does have a [ReportProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.80).aspx) method that fires a ProgressChanged event that you can subscribe to.

One overload accepts an "object" as userstate - you can use that to report your intermediate data.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem on having an object storing those values? And maybe some other indicating that those values have changed?

With proper locking, this shouldn't be an issue

## Update

Assuming you can already invoke your actions in the main thread (if not, [this link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/305882/how-do-i-invoke-functions-on-the-main-thread.html) may provide some help, although I've never used Unity so you'll need to trust the users in the unity forum), you could use a pattern like:

Somewhere:

```
object MyResult;
bool MyResultIsModified = false;
```

Within code the on the main thread:

```
// ... perform your actions here ...

lock(MyResult)
{
  MyResult = <data you want to gather on your thread>;
  MyResultIsModified = true;
}
```

Inside your thread/backgroundworker/whatever loop:

```
lock(MyResult)
{
  if(MyResultIsModified)
  {
    // ... do whatever with MyResult ..
    MyResultIsModified = false;
  }
}
```

If `MyResult` is a value type then you'd need to have another object for the purpose of locking, but that's about it

Comment: That looks promising, I will check it out!